# Does Black-Scholes imply that the expected return for an asset is fixed as the volatility increases?

Tags: options, option-pricing, asset-pricing

I'm new to this, and just trying to understand what options prices imply about asset growth. I'm looking at the following expression for the underlying asset price in the Black-Scholes model, in particular:

`S(t) = S(0)*exp((r - 0.5*\sigma^2)*dt + \sigma*dW(t)`

Where `S(t)` is the asset price at time `t` in years, `r` is the risk-free rate, `\sigma` is the volatility.

Which, implies that that expected price of the asset at time `t` can be computed as `exp(rt)` -- independent of `\sigma`.

What I'm trying to understand is why a rational investor would purchase a risky asset if the expected growth rate was the same as the risk-free rate. Wouldn't it be expected that if an asset is more risky then investors would only purchase it if it offered higher returns than a risk-free asset?

Comment: This equation describes the Stock Price *in the Risk Neutral Measure Q*. It can be used in modeling option prices, but when considering stock investing we would use the "natural measure" P in which the the appreciation of the stock is $\mu > r$. In other words we are pricing the option "as if" this is the equation for the stock, but it does not describe the real world of stock investing. This is a rather subtle point, the different measures P and Q, is difficult to grasp at first.

Comment: "trying to understand what options prices imply about asset growth": So, the Black Scholes theory says option prices do not tell us anything about asset growth. The long term rate of growth simply does not enter into the formula for the option price. Options are a bet on the volatility $\sigma$

Comment: And there is a different model that describes the expected return on a stock based on how risky the stock is - the Capital Asset Pricing Model.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @nbbo2 and @dm63, I guess in the real world then market makers and options traders do not use the risk-neutral measure when pricing options? Instead they would have some proprietary mechanisms for deriving a `\mu` and use that?

Comment: No, the job of a stock investor is to figure out what $\mu$ is.  Options traders just take the stock price as given and use the risk neutral measure to price options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, Black-Scholes assumes a risk-neutral measure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).